# preg_replace everything after forward slash /

Tags: php

I'm getting an error with this. I'm trying to remove all chars after / is found in the string.

e.g. 'google.com/remove' should become 'google.com'

```
preg_replace ( '////.*/' , '' , $string);
```

Message: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/'

Comment: You need to escape your slashes. (`\/`) Ignore the fact that this looks like a butt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `preg_replace` to do that.

```
// PHP 5.4
$string = explode('/', $string, 2)[0];

// Before PHP 5.4
$string = array_shift(explode('/', $string, 2));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
preg_replace ('/\/(.*)/' , '' , $string);
```

Can't test it at the moment, but it should work...

EDIT: Tested online quickly, working as expected :)